# How can I be assured that rsyslog complies with RFC5424 (I haven't found any direct mention on rsyslog documentation)?

Tags: rsyslog

I have a requirement for a system that specifies RFC5424 base for event logging services.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622801/does-linuxs-rsyslog-support-rfc-5424 Might be of interest